# Having issue with React Flatpickr onchange

Tags: reactjs, flatpickr

I am trying to change flatpickr date in handlePickerChange function. I keep picker in state initially.

```
const [pickerR, setPickerR] = useState([])
```

This how I set initial values of pickers in useffect.

```
const temp = []
resData?.contract_requisite.map((val, ind) => {
    temp.push({ 
        [`companies_signature_date`]: val?.companies_signature_date,
        [`contract_signature_date`]: val?.contract_signature_date 
    })
})
setPicker(temp)
```

The main issue is when I try to console picker inside my onchange function. it returns empty array however it should be and it is not.

Here is my onchange function

```
console.log(pickerE)
const handlePickerChange = (_, __, e) => {
    console.log(picker)
}
```

Im trying to handle changes but somehow picker's state value return empty inside onchange function, however right before function it returns actual values.
Do you have some clue, what is or could be the reason?

I actually tried different approaches and it works okay. but it is still big question how it works.